# Return item i+1 instead of item i at List

Tags: c#, .net, class, observablecollection

I have a list of some objects. like below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Property > Items { get; private set; }
```

Now I need when clients ask item i, instead of i I send item i+1. It is not possible that when list is filling I change the arrangement. Also it is not possible that when user call Items instead of i, they call i+1.

So the best possible way is that I override the `get` method for this property in way that instead of object in index of i return object in index of  i+1 . Is it possible?

Comment: You need to return your own class with that logic in its indexer.

Comment: How about locking it?

Comment: Do you *have* to return `ObservableCollection<>`? If you could make the property `IList<T>` it would be simpler.

Comment: I use collectionChanged method. So it think it should be ObservableCollection<>

Comment: @SLaks may you specify more?

Comment: @Yosi, also may you specify more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed, you can just create your own collection type based on `ObservableCollection<T>` and modify the indexer accordingly. The only problem is that you can't just override the indexer, as it's not virtual, but you can instead wrap an `ObservableCollection<T>` into a class, delegate all work to it, but modify the indexer implementation to add one to the getter access:

```
public class PlusOneObservableCollection<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> innerCollection;

    public PlusOneObservableCollection()
    {
        this.innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        this.innerCollection.CollectionChanged += InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }
    public PlusOneObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        this.innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(collection);
        this.innerCollection.CollectionChanged += InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void InnerCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = this.CollectionChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return this.innerCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        this.innerCollection.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        this.innerCollection.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            //Here is where the actual change takes place
            return this.innerCollection[index + 1];
        }
        set
        {
            this.innerCollection[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.innerCollection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.innerCollection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.innerCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return this.innerCollection.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

With this approach, you'll however need to change the property type, as it no longer inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>`, but from `IList<T>` now. Having it implementing the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface however makes users able to subscribe to change notifications.